# Huge heap dump file, but profiler states heap is small

Tags: java, memory-leaks

So I have a `20 GB` heap dump file.

When I open it up with `jhat` and `Memory Analyzer` I see that the overall size of all objects is appoximately 2.3Gb.

So, naturally the question is, why? The heap cannot be empty, it was running out of memory.

Is the serialized size of the heap dramatically different from the size when it is actually in use in the JVM?

I also opened it up with a hex editor, and I do not see huge portions of it being empty.

Comment: how did you get the heap dump file (OOM, jmap, or some other tools)?

Comment: We used jmap to build hprof dump.

Comment: did you include 'live' option? If not that would explain the issue

Comment: Was heap dump extracted from core dump?

Comment: Did you check "include unreachable object" in MAT preferences?

Comment: Keep in mind that once the heap has reached some "high water mark" it never gets smaller.  The amount of OCCUPIED storage may be less, but the total amount of storage allocated for use by the heap never decreases.